# openpyxl - Write string beginning with equals ('=')

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm pulling some random text strings from a database and writing them to an xlsx file with openpyxl. Some of the strings happen to start with an equals sign (something like "=134lj9adsasf&^") This leads to the problem of Excel trying to interpret it as a formula and showing it as "#NAME?" due to the error.

In Excel itself, I can avoid this problem by changing the cell's format from General to Text prior to  writing the string. I tried to do this with openpyxl but it doesn't make a difference. When I open the generated spreadsheet it does show the cell as having text format, but it still shows the error. How can I get around this?

A working example is below. When I open the file in Excel, it shows #NAME? for the third cell. Yet if I simply select the cell and type "=abc?123" (without quotes), Excel accepts the text with no issue.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.cell.cell import Cell

stringList = [("abc","123","=abc?123","ok")]
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.create_sheet('Sheet1')
for row in stringList:
    ws.append(row)
    for idx, cell in enumerate(ws[ws.max_row]):
        cell.number_format = '@'  # Set all cells to text format to avoid issue with =
        cell.value = str(row[idx]) # Re-write data
wb.save("filename.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. Just need to change the data_type rather than number_format.

The strings starting with equals had their data_type set to 'f'.

```
for row in stringList:
    ws.append(row)
    for cell in ws[ws.max_row]:
        if cell.data_type == 'f':
            cell.data_type = 's'
```

[image: excel]